# Identifier expected error with multi line string

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image]

I'm working with node , trying to build jupyter notebooks programatically. I'm trying to create a function that will build a notebook 'code' type cell. After working in the repl I have:

```
function codeCell(arr =>  
  `{
  cell_type: 'code',
  execution_count: null,
  metadata: { tags: [] },
  outputs: [],
  source: [${arr}]
}`
);
```

As you can see in the screenshot I'm getting an identifier expected error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is called a "template literal", not multi-line string.

Comment: It looks like your IDE doesn't recognize ES6 features like arrow functions and template literals. Make sure you've configured the proper JavaScript version.

Comment: @Barmar , Thank you. I'm using vscdode and made some changes following https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_writing-jsconfigjson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function codeCell(arr =>
```

You started defining an arrow function **inside the argument list of a function definition,** which is invalid syntax.

Either write

```js
function codeCell(arr) {
  return `{
    cell_type: 'code',
    execution_count: null,
    metadata: { tags: [] },
    outputs: [],
    source: [${arr}]
  }`;
}
```

Or if you want to use the arrow function syntax:

```js
const codeCell = (arr) => `{
  cell_type: 'code',
  execution_count: null,
  metadata: { tags: [] },
  outputs: [],
  source: [${arr}]
}`;
```